# Tomcat: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target

Tags: java, jsf

I`ve problem with Tomcat. My JSF app is building and server has started, but comes with ERROR "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Tomcat dosent even show his page @http://localhost:8080

Tomcat page is starting @localhost when I using startup.bat

Why app dosent starting [users.xthml] by RunAs -> Run on Server?

[image]